# Django model filter elements

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have four models as follows:

```
class modelA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class modelB(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(...)
    A = models.ForeignKey(modelA, ...)

class modelC(models.Model):
    
    email = models.CharField(...)
    B = models.ForeignKey(modelB, ...)

class modelD(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(...)
    C = models.ForeignKey(modelC)
```

Given `modelA` element id, I have to filter `modelD` elements based on that id. But I am not sure about how to do that.

I appreciate any ideas!

Comment: any response for ans did it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

```
modalD.objects.filter(C__B__A__name ='name')
```

when you use double underscore you filter the related Inheritance modal